# Cannot get oAuth to work with Laravel and BigCommerce App

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, bigcommerce

I am having issues setting up the "One-Click-App" oAuth on Bigcommerce with the [BC PHP API](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php) library.

The issue at the moment is getting the actual auth token. I've tried various methods and believe it's down to the (Code/Context/Scope) get requests. They return as `null` every time.

I've tried both:

```
$request->query('code');
$request->get('code');
```

On the BC app launch screen I am presented with:

```
Trying to get property 'access_token' of non-object
```

Which of course is because the token is returning null.

**Here is my controller in Laravel**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

class BController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
      $object = new \stdClass();
      $object->client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      $object->client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      $object->redirect_uri = 'https://linkto/process_oauth_result';
      $object->code = $request->query('code');
      $object->context = $request->query('context');
      $object->scope = $request->query('scope');
      Bigcommerce::useJson();

      $authTokenResponse = Bigcommerce::getAuthToken($object);

      // configure BC App
      Bigcommerce::configure([
     'client_id' => env('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
     'auth_token' => $authTokenResponse->access_token,
     'store_hash' => 'xxxxxxx'
   ]);

        Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

        return 'Success!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that this works fine. I am using Runcloud to manage the app and the `click-jacking` option was blocking the iframe on the app screen!